# How to use tab indentation in the whole document (PhpStorm)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I have set the configuration of PhpStorm to use tab indentation but it doesn't work as I expected so I wonder if there is any solution for what I want. So the editor use tabs at the beginning of every line but after I write any word and use the tab character again it uses spaces instead. This is driving me crazy, I'd appreciate some help!

Here are some images to help understand more what I want...

Here is how it currently works in PhpStorm:

[image: phpstorm]

And this is how I'd like it to work:

[image: vscode]

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling "Smart tabs" checkbox at File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP > **Tabs and Indents** tab

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! It worked... I really appreciate your help!